# How does Xdocument save method work?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I'm building a Windows phone 8 App. I already have an XML and when the app starts, it should load the data from the XML to `Longlistselectors`.

I have a background worker to load the XML from a URL, save to another XML file and then reload that XML and update the `Longlistselector`.

Here is the code:

```
 private async void BwDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load("APPSDATA.xml");
        var listnode = from c in xdoc.Descendants("Ungdung") select c;
        var xElements = listnode as IList<XElement> ?? listnode.ToList();
        foreach (var xElement in xElements)
        {
            var element = xElement.Element("Id");
            if (element != null)
            {
                var appId = element.Value;
                var appVersion = await GetAppsVersion(appId);
                xElement.SetElementValue("Version", appVersion.ToString());
            }
        }
        var file = new FileStream("APPSDATA.xml", FileMode.Open);

        xdoc.Save(file);
    }
```

The strange thing here is this: I don't know when that `foreach` loop finishes its job so I set thread sleep in 10s in `RunWorkerCompleted` method. After this, if I exit the app and restart it, the `XML` with new info will be loaded.

But if I tried to do anything in `WorkerCompleted` after that thread sleep, the XML is not saved.

I have no idea about this. Anyone have a solution for this?
Sorry for my bad English.

```
private void BwRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        SystemTray.SetIsVisible(this, false);  

    }
```

Comment: Save method isn't your problem, you don't seem to understand how `backgroundworker` and `thread.sleep` work, when the final line in do work has completed, then run worker completed will be called, no idea why thread.sleep would make a difference, all it will do is pause execution **Edit** XDocument takes a filepath as a parameter so no idea what the filestream is for

Comment: Xdocument save method only accept Stream, TextWriter or XmlWriter :|

Comment: [This?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx)